# Scope of Promise's resolve

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, es6-promise

I am calling a third party library function. 
It returns results ( from their api ) and a callback function which I can call for next set of results.

To simply things, I have created a mock third party function.

My question is why `resolve` is not resolving promise after 1st time. I am guessing it's happening because `resolve` is being scoped inside inner function of third party library.

How can I fix this ? Is there a better way to achieve this ?

```js
// Third party function, I cannot control
function thirdParty(callback) {

  var number = 0;

  var inner = function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      next = inner;
      number = number + 10;
      callback(number, next);
    }, 1000);
  };

  inner();
}

// Code I can control
var nextFunc = null;

// Calls third party api
function getNumber() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    if (nextFunc) {
      nextFunc();
    } else {
      thirdParty(function(number, next) {
       console.log(number);
        nextFunc = next;
        resolve(number);
      });
    }
  });
}

function onButtonClick() {
  getNumber().then(function(number) {
    document.getElementById('ele').innerHTML += number + '<br>';
  });
}
```

```html
<p>
<button type="button" onClick="onButtonClick();">Get Numbers
</button>
</p>
<p id="ele"></p>
```

Comment: "My question is why resolve is not resolving promise after 1st time." Can you clarify?

Comment: Click on 'Get Numbers' button. It does not print after 1st time.  But `console.log(number)` is logging each time. `resolve(number)` only resolves the Promise one time, and does nothing on subsequent calls.

Comment: what would be the expected output in the snippet btw? 10,20,30,40,.... or 10,10,10,10,... ?

Comment: @Jashwant are you intentionally using ES5 syntax or is it okay to use, say ES2018 syntax for async iterator support?

Comment: "*why resolve is not resolving promise after 1st time*" - because you never call `resolve()` after the first `getNumber()` call? You only ever call `nextFunc()` when it exists, and disregard the `resolve` function of that promise.

Comment: Are you sure that this "`inner`" function of the third party does not accept its own callback argument? If yes, that's a really horrible API.

Comment: @Bergi, no it does not take any argument whatsoever.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts, I am using `Promise`, just because I know it better than async, await.

Comment: @Bergi, can you explain in other words, may be in an answer ? Because `console.log` is working fine. `resolve` and `console.log` both are part of same callback.

Comment: @Jashwant But the `resolve` that you call in the callback passed to `thirdParty` is the one that is resolving the promise that is created in the first call to `getNumber`. Calling it multiple times won't do anything, and it certainly will not start to resolve unrelated promises.

Comment: @Jashwant out of curiosity, do you have a link to this third party API function you've mocked here?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts `https://github.com/Airtable/airtable.js/blob/2dad5fe2b5d7551fe67971c67fd7ad1be0a5f80f/lib/query.js#L61`

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't resolve because `nextFunc()` eventually calls the callback passed to `thirdParty()` inside the *first* promise, and calls `resolve()` on that promise again, which has already been settled, so it does nothing. Meanwhile, you never call `resolve()` on the second promise, so it never settles.

Here's <s>a better approach</s> the only approach I can think of, given the limitations of your third party API (which has horrible interface design, in my opinion):

```js
// Third party function, I cannot control
function thirdParty(callback) {

  var number = 0;

  var inner = function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      next = inner;
      number = number + 10;
      callback(number, next);
    }, 1000);
  };

  inner();
}

// Code I can control
const numbers = getNumbers();

// Calls third party api
async function* getNumbers() {
  let resolve, next;

  yield new Promise(_resolve => {
    resolve = _resolve;

    thirdParty((number, _next) => {
      console.log(number);
      resolve(number);
      next = _next;
    });
  });

  while (true) {
    yield new Promise(_resolve => {
      resolve = _resolve;
      next();
    });
  }
}

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  numbers.next().then(({ value }) => {
    document.getElementById('ele').innerHTML += value + '<br>';
  });
});
```

```html
<p>
  <button type="button">Get Numbers</button>
</p>
<p id="ele"></p>
```

Comment: I was thinking the same reason for not resolving. Sorry, couldn't explain it in better words. I'lll try your solution. Though it's not something I was hoping for, but I guess I'll have to deal with it because of limitations of library.

Comment: It doesn't seem like this interface was ever intended for pausing iteration. They probably only considered use-cases where someone might set a timeout inside the callback to call next after a short delay or something